# Disable "Natural" Scrolling for the Vertical Direction Only?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, scrolling, touchpad

In [Apple OS X Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/), how can I disable ["natural" scrolling](http://www.csmonitor.com/Innovation/Latest-News-Wires/2011/0721/Apple-s-natural-scrolling-feels-horribly-unnatural.-Here-s-why) for up-and-down but leave it for left-to-right?

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a little while to find a method of doing this without third-party software however I did not find one readily available. The best option I have found is the following:

[Scroll Reverser](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/37872/scroll-reverser)

Take a Look See if it meets your needs.